# How to Solve for Zero

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$4x^2e^{-x^2}-2e^{-x^2}=0$$
I took out a common factor of $2e^{-x^2}$ which got me to:
$2e^{-x^2}(2x^2-1)=0$
I'm not sure if taking out the common factor helped at all and I don't know where to go from here. Exact form only please!

Comment: Hint: Is the exponential function ever equal to zero?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You can format math to make it easier to read by following the tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Multiply across by $\frac{1}{2} e^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your start is exactly the desirable way to proceed. So you've found that

$$f(x) = \left(2e^{\left(-x^{\large 2}\right)}\right)\left(2x^2-1\right)=0$$

$f(x)$ is thus the product of two factors. So $\;f(x) = 0 \iff\;$ at least *one factor* must equal zero.

The factor $2e^{-x^2}$ will never equal zero. Why not?

That leaves $$\begin{align} f(x) = 0 \;
& \iff\;\;2x^2 - 1 = 0 \\ \\
& \iff \;x^2 - 1/2 = 0 \\ \\
& \iff\; \left(x + \sqrt{1/2}\right)\left(x - \sqrt{1/2}\right) = 0 \\ \\
& \iff \;x = \pm \sqrt{1/2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: clean answer! +1

Answer (score 4):

$4x^2 e^{-x^2}-2e^{-x^2}=0$

$2 e^{-x^2}\left(2x^2-1\right)=0$

Which is essentially true if either $2e^{-x^2}=0$ or $2x^2-1=0$

But $e^{-x^2}$ is never zero for any nice $x$.

$\therefore 2x^2-1=0$

You should be able to solve this one.

Comment: I can solve this, thank you. That explains why I was having so much trouble. I forgot for a moment $e^{-x^2}$ can never equal zero. This is actually the second derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ and I am trying to figure out concavity and points of inflection.

Comment: So by equating the 2nd derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ you're getting the inflection points at $x=\pm\sqrt{1/2}$. You may want to relate it with this plot of $e^{-x^2}$ in [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e^%28-x^2%29). Moreover, there is a special name for this type of bell-shaped curve. It's called the Gaussian Curve.